# Will caching or background job improve my Rails App performance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, caching, heroku

My Rails App syncs calendar events from gmail through the [Nylas API](https://www.nylas.com/). I am storing all the events and associated calendars on my app (either creating new or updating existing).  It takes a very long time, in fact, I get timeout errors on my Heroku hosted Rails App whenever I try to sync a calendar.  Not sure why it takes a very long time.  So to react, I want to either start caching (using Redis or Memcached) the data (still don't know exactly how I will do that) OR run the sync in a background job (using Delayed_Job or Resque).

I wanted to know how others would tackle this problem.  Would appreciate some feedback on not only what approach to take, but pointers in *how* would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need fast, persistent access within your app to a large set of calendar events that are ultimately sourced from an external system, then I'd create (in fact have already created) models for the calendars and the events. The structure ought to be fairly obvious from the structure of the API, and I would just persist them in your database so you can use ActiveRecord methods to retrieve/sort them.

It's unlikely that you'd need a caching layer on top of the model.

Synchronisation is definitely a background job.

Comment: perhaps the way I have implemented it is incorrect, but I do have models that map to the API.  When user goes to Calendar, they will sync to get latest calendar events from google and also push any new ones created on my app to google.  The thing is, I am syncing for all users of a "firm" (customer).  That could be as high as 20 users.  I am also grabbing all calendar events (where i think i can do a better job by chunking somehow).

Comment: When do I synchronize? Everytime the user visits the calendar page?  That could lead to race conditions on my app.  Or is it just better to only load the month's worth of calendar events (the default view is month)?  The thing is, one user can see any other user's events (based on permission), so I kinda have to load all users' events.

Comment: You could use a background job to synchronise on a schedule, which is what Google Calendar does with remote linked calendars. Let them choose hourly, 6 hourly, daily, weekly, and maybe have a button for "synchronise now"?

Comment: Thanks!  I think I like that approach better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both but majorly background jobs, delayed_job or sidekiq. 
You can also run a cron task that periodically update the calendar data in your app.

To fetch data you can fetch from memory store then database, where memcache will be useful.

Comment: Where you state memcache, I can use Redis in its place as well, right?

Comment: Also, I want the update to be on-demand.  So when user asks to sync, I will run background job.  I am afraid that might cause race conditions though since the background job will be adding/deleting events at the same time as the end-user, who will be doing it online.

Comment: Both memcache and redis does in-memory store, but memcache integration is easier for object caching.  On-demand sync should happen in background job as you said, race conditions should be taken care by google calendar itself.

Comment: I am talking about race conditions on my app (because i persist all the data from google).